# Why 'mapify.js' doesn't work on Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I found this library to ajust map's  'coords' automacally and to paint map area when mouse is over that area.

It works perfectly on firefox but I am having some odd behaviours while on google chrome. I tryed many things to make it work, but with no success. It simply doesn't work on google chrome.

Here a jsfiddle so you can see it yourself:
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/j1dftnkp/5/)

Sample code HTML:
`<img id="imgFile" width="654px" height="1229px" border="0"
 src="http://pds15.egloos.com/pds/201001/17/91/a0030191_4b52312f4e55c.jpg" usemap="#mapa"/>
<map id="mapa"><area id="11" shape="poly" coords="315,245,258,241,224,267,223,292,230,319,250,333,309,315"/></map>`

Javascript code:
`$("img[usemap]").mapify();`

It should change background color when the mouse pointer is over the chest area. I don't know if I missed something.

Here's the plugin's official web site: [mapify.js](http://etiennemartin.ca/mapify/)

In this web site works on google chrome normally.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I missed attribute "name='mapa'" on map tag. After that it worked perfectly!

Here is the updated jsFiddle:
[Updated code](http://jsfiddle.net/alysonsm/j1dftnkp/6/)

```
<map name="mapa" id="mapa">
```